# Liferay 7 - Knowledge base versus Web contents

Tags: liferay, webcontent

I'm working on Liferay 7 and I have a question on using the portlet Knowledge Base or Web contents. I'm wondering which one is the best to do a FAQ.

Web contents can now be organized in folders, have tags and plenty of informations. KB seems to offer the same capabilities but the content is limited to Markdown script.

Does someone used the KB and have feedback on it ?

Any advice appreciated !
Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small set of FAQ and you require a simple implementation, the web content will suit you as they are simple.
The knowledge base is good fit for web-book kind of things.
If you have dynamic FAQ where people can add edit the answers or where multiple answers are required, you can go for message boards. It has an `application display template(ADT)` for Q&A as well. I am not very sure but a message broad with Q&A template can be limited to one answer only (with GUI configuration) to function like FAQ.
The other way is to download the message broad Q&A ADT from Liferay sources and tweak it to display as FAQ. This will not require much effort and this will provide for the dynamism in FAQ functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'll look at messages board and the ADT.